# Sorry, you are not allowed to list users

Tags: rest-api

When I hit: https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users

I am getting response:

```
{
"code": "rest_user_cannot_view",
"message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to list users.",
"data": {
"status": 401
}
}
```

I am able to view users in admin and via REST API I can create and modify posts so I am authenticated but for some reason I am unable to list users.  This user has administrator role.

Anyone know what issue could be?

Comment: Are you authenticated to the REST API before attempting to see the users? Being logged in to `wp-admin` doesn't necessarily mean you've authenticated to the REST API.

Answer (score 5):

I discovered it was wordfence plugin.  It blocks this endpoint.

You can disable it with this option:

[image]